# Redux-Saga non-ajax related callback issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

So, i'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to convert the following [example](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/#toc-load) to using sagas as its not an ajax related async problem:

```js
var dogBarkingBuffer = null;
// Fix up prefixing
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();

function loadDogSound(url) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

  // Decode asynchronously
  request.onload = function() {
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
      dogBarkingBuffer = buffer;
    }, onError);
  }
  request.send();
}
```

The problem i'd finding is *not* the `XMLHttpRequest` related stuff but rather how to deal with the `decodeAudioData(data, callback)` which only gives you the returned data via a callback and thus I want to trigger an action i there to add this to my Redux store.

My saga looks like this at the moment  but the missing yield in front of decodeAudio seems like a problem:

```js
import { takeLatest } from "redux-saga";
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import axios from "axios";

import * as acts from "actions/playList";


const audioFileRequest = (url) => {
  return axios.get(url, {
    withCredentials: true,
    responseType: "arraybuffer",
  })
  .then(({ data }) => data)
  .catch(({ error }) => error);
};

const decodeAudio = (undecodedData, audioContext) => {
  return audioContext.decodeAudioData(undecodedData, (buffer) => {
    acts.recivedAudioFile(buffer);  // no yeald ???
  });
};

function *fetchAudio({ url, audioContext }) {
  try {
    let rawAudioData = yield call(audioFileRequest, url);
    decodeAudio(rawAudioData, audioContext); // no yield ???
  }
  catch (error) {
    yield put(acts.errorFetchingAudioFile(error));
  }
}

export function *watchFetchAudio() {
  yield takeLatest(acts.AUDIO_FILE_REQUEST, fetchAudio);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can convert the decode audio function using es6-promise and use redux saga call method.

```
const decodeAudio = ({rawAudioData, audioContext}) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        audioContext.decodeAudioData(rawAudioData, (buffer) => {
            resolve({buffer}); // or reject if failed
        });
    }).then(({buffer}) => buffer).catch(error => error)
};

function *fetchAudio({ url, audioContext }) {
    try {
        let rawAudioData = yield call(audioFileRequest, url);
        let buffer = yield call(decodeAudio, {rawAudioData, audioContext});
        acts.recivedAudioFile(buffer);
    }
    catch (error) {
        yield put(acts.errorFetchingAudioFile(error));
    }
}
```

Comment: When out after I wrote this and thought of this myself. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Cheers.. :) @CpILL